# Asp.net mvc @Section equivlanet in Zend framework mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, zend-framework, razor

I know in asp.net mvc you can define sections in your view using something like @Section {}, and they in your layout you can using them to position/display where you want the information to be. is there anything equivalent to that in zend framework mvc ? an example would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Either a [view partial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial) or [placeholders](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.view.placeholders.basics.html) are roughly equivalent to the sections you are referring to from ASP.NET.

The placeholder documentation even shows an example of rending custom sidebar content.

To use a view helper just create a view script in your `views/scripts` directory and name it with a `.phtml` extension and put the content in it that you want.

```
//application/views/scripts/sidebar.phtml
<div id="sidebar">
    Welcome <?php echo $this->username ?>
</div>
```

In your layout or view where you want to display the content from the view partial, you would call:

```
<?php echo $this->partial('sidebar.phtml', array('username' => 'drew010')) ?>
```

The above call results in a rendering of sidebar.phtml using the `username` variable passed in.  View partials have an isolated variable scope so you are able to pass variables in as an array and use them within the partial.

Using a placeholder is similar but the content of the placeholder can be set in a number of ways.  Accessing the placeholder content is slightly different as well.

Let's say in your layout you have:

```
<?php /* output sidebar from placeholder value "sidebar" */ ?>
<?php echo $this->placeholder('sidebar'); ?>
```

The placeholder content could be set by rendering a view script that captures the output or assigned directly to the placeholder itself.

The most basic example of assigning content to a placeholder is:

```
<?php
// from controller:
$this->view->placeholder('sidebar')->set('<div id="sidebar">content</div>');
```

The manual on placeholders goes into more detail on how to assign, append, prepend, and manage content in placeholders.

Either should suit your purpose for replacing sections from ASP.NET.

Comment: I'll try it out tonight and see if i can get it to work, anyways thanks for the solution.

Comment: You're welcome.  Placeholders are good but depending on your needs, the view partials may be what you should look into first.

Comment: You know what i hate about stackoverflow, when you ask a question, no matter how bad it is phrased or how stupid the question is, people should not give it a minus rating, just cz they know something in doesn't mean they should insult others by degrading them